# How to retrieve object properties with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have this object:

```
public class Foo
{
     public string FirstProp {get;set;}
     public string SecondProp {get;set;}
     public string ThirdProp {get;set;}
}
```

Now I would like to retrieve only the FirstProp and the SecondProp from that object and concat all the property values into one string.

I have one solution in mind which would't be clean imo. Here it is:

```
var foo = new Foo("test1","test2","test3");
var propertyNames = new[] {"FirstProp", "SecondProp"};
var properties = foo.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => propertyNames.Contains(x.Name));
//Then loop through each retrieved property and concat the string
```

So basically I am just looking for a cleaner solution where I wouldn't be dependent on an array of string.

Comment: I think the downvotes were a little trigger happy.  Regardless, maybe indicate more clearly what type of result you are looking for, perhaps with that result included in the pseudocode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var foo = new Foo(...);
var result = string.Join(",", new[]{ foo.FirstProp, foo.SecondProp });
```

Does this suffice? Or do you need Reflection for dynamic typing? If so, one can also supply MemberExpressions to dynamically get the values. Are you dealing with a collection of instances? Do you need this functionality extracted in a helper-method with a parameter for the needed properties?

Comment: This does not do what you think it does. These values are whatever the variable contains, not the actual name of the variable itself.

Comment: I know exactly what this code does, the question is, whether it matches the requirements, which are imho quite vague. I am still hoping for some clarification - until then, my answer stands as it is.

Comment: Where does my question lack some clarifications?